# How to reshape a (1D) flat list to a 2D list of lists array without using numpy?

Tags: python, list

I have flat lists like this:

`A [2, -4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, -1]`
`B [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

and I want to reshape them into

A [[2, -4, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 4, -1]]

B [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

Is there a light-weight function to do this without using numpy?

Comment: `I have a list` ... what you posted for your list definition is not valid Python code.

Comment: Why do you still label numpy when you don't want to use it?

Comment: It seems like you are asking for the opposite of flattening. If you google chunking instead of flattening, you will find a lot of answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Please use tags to indicate what the question **is** about, not what it isn't about. If you want to solve a problem *without* Numpy, then don't tag it `numpy`. Anyway, please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

sure you can use this recipe with `iter` and `zip` to group by a size

```
def group_size(L,size):
    return list(zip(*[iter(L)]*size))

print(group_size([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3))
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain why and how it works?

Comment: Notice that `group_size()` returns a list of tuples (and not a list of lists).

Answer (score -2):

OK, there is an excellent answer by *Joran Beasley* so let's use it along with a recipe for flattening a list in a function able to reshape both flat and a 2D lists to desired shape:

```
def reshape_list(L, xsize, ysize=None, fillna=False):
    if isinstance(L[0], list):
        _L = [] 
        for l in L: _L+=l
        L = _L 
    if not fillna: 
        if ysize:
            assert xsize*ysize == len(L)
        else: 
            assert len(L)%xsize == 0
        return list(map(list,zip(*[iter(L)]*xsize)))
    else: 
        gap = []
        if ysize:
            if xsize*ysize > len(L): 
                gap = [None]*(xsize*ysize - len(L))
        else: 
            v, r = divmod(len(L),xsize)
            gap = [None]*r
        return list(map(list, zip(*[iter(L+gap)]*xsize)))

print(reshape_list([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2)) 
print(reshape_list([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 3))
```

gives:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And as we are reshaping lists it might be also of interest how to transpose a 2D list as transposing a 2D list will deliver another result as reshaping:

```
def transpose_2D_list(L):
    return list(map(list,zip(*L)))

print(transpose_2D_list([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]))
```

gives:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

^-- notice the difference to reshaping with xsize=3